# Can you open the native iPhone mail app with OpenURL but not for compose?

Tags: iphone

Can you open the native iPhone mail app with OpenURL but not for compose? I just want to open the app into the inbox, or at the very least just open it (and doesn't care which account/folder it shows). I just don't want the compose page shown.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so, I come to that conclusion from going over this document https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html